# DataGridView does not update after delete, update or insert

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I have a `DatagGridView` which has a `DataSet` from an Access database. I have a problem when I delete, update or insert data.

This is an example from my update method.

```
Private Sub btnactualizar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnactualizar.Click
    novacios()
    Try
        con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ruta)
        con.Open()
        Dim actualiza As String = "UPDATE Usuarios SET nombre_real=@a1, correo = @a2, pass = @a3, activo = @a4 WHERE Correo = @a5"
        sentencia = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(actualiza)
        sentencia.Connection = con
        sentencia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", txtusuarios.Text)
        sentencia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", txtmail.Text)
        sentencia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", txtpass.Text)
        sentencia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", txtactivo.Text)
        sentencia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", txtusuarios.Text)
        sentencia.ExecuteReader()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Actualización realzada con éxito", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Me.UsuariosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Bd_proyectoNDataSet.Usuarios)
        limpiatextos()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ex.Message.ToString()
    End Try
End Sub
```

As we can see after the messagebox, the list should be updated with the fill method. But the datagrid is still the same.

Here some pictures to understand what I'm talking about. I will appreciate any help.

**Before updating the data**
[image: Here's before update the data. See the datagrid]

**After updating the data. Nothing happened**
[image: And here's after I updated the data. Nothing happened]

Comment: `sentencia.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing things backwards.  Don't make a change to the database and then try to update the grid from there.  You update the local data first and then save that change to the database.

Your grid is bound to a `BindingSource` and that is bound to a `DataTable` in your typed `DataSet`.  That's where you should be making the change.  It may be that you should be binding your `TextBoxes` to the same data, in which case the modifications to the data would happen automatically.  If not then you should be copying the data from the `TextBoxes` back into the typed `DataRow` you're editing.  That grid will automatically reflect that change.  YOu then call `Update` on your table adapter to save those changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.

In short, don't make changes directly to the database and then try to pull those changes from the database into your local data.  Make the changes to the local data first, then save those changes to the database.